# CISCO 9800-L Controller internal dhcp not working - GUEST WIFI

Tags: cisco, networking, dhcp, ieee-802.11, cisco-wlc

I have been trying to configure a guest network for my Cisco Catalyst 9800-L Wireless Controller for some days now. For the guest network, i want it to use an internal dhcp on the controller. I have been trying for days now, however, when a client connects to guest WIFI network it does not receive a DHCP IP address.
POOL:
ip dhcp pool localpool
network 10.10.96.0 255.255.248.0
default-router 10.101.11.1
dns-server 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 10.101.11.1
lease infinite
[image]

SVI of vlan 10 was created for DHCP pool
interface Vlan10
description VLAN 10
ip address pool localpool
ip helper-address 10.25.13.73
no autostate
[image]
Management is on : GigabitEthernet0
and TwoGigabitEthernet0/0/3 will provide internet connectivity for guest network - gateway is 10.101.11.1
[image]

Guest network policy snaps:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hoping to get some help. First time I am configuring a CISCO WLC 9800. I got the internal network wlan to work to radius server on Windows NPS but this guest network using internal dhcp pool is a pain.

Regards,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: VLAN 10 must be a layer-3 interface, and the default gw MUST be within the same LAN; doesn't have to be the AP, 'tho

Answer (score 2):

Your pool is misconfigured.  The default gateway will be the router interface on VLAN 10 and must be in the same subnet as the pool.